# Video filters are slow

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am adding a filter to a pre-recorded video however when the filter is applied the video lags and is slower.

Help is much appreciated.

```
func applyFilters(){
     let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(self.editVideo(_:)))
     displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
output = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: nil)
player?.currentItem?.addOutput(output)
player.play()
}
func editVideo(link: CADisplayLink){
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")!
let itemTime = output.itemTimeForHostTime(CACurrentMediaTime())
if output.hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime(itemTime){
    if let pixelBuffer = output.copyPixelBufferForItemTime(itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: nil){
        let image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        filter.setValue(image, forKeyPath: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let output = filter.outputImage {
            let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, fromRect: output.extent)
            let processedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
            filtersImageView.image = processedImage
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying on a simulator?

Comment: No, I'm trying on a device. iPhone 5s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `CIContext` for each frame which is very performance expensive. Create a property like `let context = CIContext()` then remove `let context = CIContext(options: nil)` from `editVideo`. You should also be aware that by default a `CIContext` will use the CPU for image processing, you can specify either an OpenGL or Metal context for better performance, though that shouldn't be necessary in this instance.

For a complete working example of what you're doing, you should check out [FlexMonkey's VideoEffects repository](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/VideoEffects)